# Compact support question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If a function $\phi(x,t)$ is $C^2$ and has compact support on $\mathbb{R}$ x $[0,T]$ does that mean that:

$\phi(x,T)=0$

$\phi(x,0)=0$

$\phi(\infty,t)=0$

$\phi(-\infty,t)=0$

as well as

$\phi_t(x,T)=0$

$\phi_t(x,0)=0$

$\phi_x(\infty,t)=0$

$\phi_x(-\infty,t)=0$

I am trying to check my understanding of this idea.

Comment: Do You mean on $\mathbb{R}\times[0,T]$? $\overline{\{(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times(0,T):\phi(x,t)\neq 0\}}$ must be compact in $\mathbb{R}\times(0,T)$ then.

Comment: Sorry I am confused if you weren't sure what $\mathbb{R}x[0,T]$ was? I meant $\mathbb{R}$ x $[0,T]$ like you said there...or if there was something else confusing.

Comment: not really, any way it´s important that the closure of the support is already contained in the open interior . so all the equations You wrote hold but are not sufficient for "compact support in..."

Comment: Oh ok. So the equations hold given the compact support but they don't imply compact support? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: Yes, that´s right. One might say "the closure of the support" must be compact "with positive distance to the boundary"

Comment: Note that not all compactly supported functions will satisfy your claim about the time derivatives.

Comment: @Eddy oh really? Do you have an example by chance? I am curious about that..

Comment: Well, if $f(x)$ is a compactly supported function of $x$, then $\phi(x, t) =f(x) t (T-t) $ is a compactly supported function of $x, t$, and if you differentiate wrt $t$ then its not zero at the boundaries.

Comment: In fact, $\phi(x, t) =f(x) $ would be compactly supported also.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help on that.

Comment: @PeterMelech Why is it important that the closure of the support be contained in the $\mathbb{R}\times(0,T)$? Isn't the definition of compact support just that the closure of the support is compact? Then if $f(x)\neq 0$ on all of $[0,T]$, then the support of $f$ is, in fact, $[0,T]$. Thus, $f$ does not vanish on the boundary.

Comment: @RebeccaHardenbrook This is why this is usually defined for functions on open sets and sometimes the symbol $sup(f)\subset\subset dom(f)$ is used, for technical purposes it is often useful to have some space between the support and the boundary